# Consola de Chrome: Refrescar solo un elemento y no toda la pagina, para ver un cambio en una campo

Tags: html, dom, chrome, console, dev-tools

Estoy testeado una página que tiene unos 50 campos de solo lectura, cada uno muestra valores que vienen de una base de datos. La página funciona bien, cuando se hace un cambio en ese campo (en la base de datos) la página muestra el cambio correctamente.

El problema es:

Para ver como se refleja el cambio debo refrescar toda la página (f5) y esto toma mucho tiempo recargando toda la página desde cero. Necesito una forma de usar la consola de Chrome para refrescar solo ese elemento HTML (el que contiene el campo que estoy probando) y agilizar la prueba. Son demasiados valores los que tengo que probar :/

Por ejemplo, sé que puedo dar órdenes al navegador desde la consola como las siguientes:

```
document.getElementById("combo-1123-trigger-picker").click();
document.getElementById("combo-1123-trigger-picker").remove();
```

Y esas funcionan. Pero, si intento con algo como:

```
document.getElementById("combo-1123-trigger-picker").reload();
```

ó algo como:

```
document.getElementById("combo-1123-trigger-picker").refresh();
```

...no funciona.

¿Existe alguna forma de actualizar solo ese elemento HTML desde la consola de Chrome o desde el Devtool en general?

Comment: hmm, ¿por qué no Ajax?

Comment: Hola @ArielMontes, gracias por comentar. 
Lo que intento es hacerlo desde el mismo navegador, con la herramienta de Developer tools de Chrome (el inspector de elementos). Esas líneas que mostré hacen efecto correctamente sobre el elemento en cuestión, cuando las introduzco en en la consola del mismo inspector de elementos. 

Pero la función load() no hace el efecto que espero. Que se refresque ese solo element, ese solo div, sin tener que cargar la pagina entera con (f5).

Comment: Es que ajax ha sido inventado para eso. Se trata solo de una librería js fácil de importar y de utilizar.